# Как правильно сформировать запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Привет друзья!
Есть таблица table_one которая связанна по id с table_two

```
table_one
id pole1 pole2 table_two_id

table_two
id text1 text2
```

Как правильно составить запрос что было получить все записи tables_one но только те у которых есть связь с tables_two и заполнено именно поле text1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table_one.* FROM table_one 
  INNER JOIN  table_two  
  ON table_one.table_two_id = table_two.id 
  WHERE table_two.text1 IS NOT NULL 
    AND table_two.text1 > ""
```

Comment: в postgresql не знаю, но в mysql `table_two.text1 > ""` отфильтрует так же и те, которые null. Это справедливо и для `table_two.text1 = ""`. Т.е. возможно, `table_two.text1 IS NOT NULL` можно удалить.

Comment: @BOPOH я тоже не знаю этих тонкостей mysql и postgresql. Например, в Oracle это тоже так, а в MS Access есть разница